# Classe "PDO" não encontrada após atualizar de PHP 7.2.13 para PHP 7.3.0 no Debian 9

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

Em um servidor com Debian 9, eu atualizei o PHP da versão 7.2.13 para a versão 7.3.0, porém agora o PDO não funciona mais.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found.
```

As libs já estão instaladas:

```
root@/# apt install php7.3-pdo
Reading packages list... Ready
Building dependences tree
Reading state informations... Ready
Note, selecting  'php7.3-common' instead of 'php7.3-pdo'
php7.3-common is already the newest version (7.3.0-1+0~20181206202713.23+stretch~1.gbp076afd).
0 packages updated, 0 new packages instaled, 0 packages to be removed e 0 packages  not updated.
root@/# apt install php7.3-mysql
Reading packages list... Ready
Building dependences tree
Reading state informations... Ready
php7.3-mysql is already the newest version (7.3.0-1+0~20181206202713.23+stretch~1.gbp076afd).
0 packages updated, 0 new packages instaled, 0 packages to be removed e 0 packages  not updated.
root@/#
```

O arquivo `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` está com `pdo_mysql` habilitado.

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

O `phpinfo()` informa que o aruqivo `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` é o `php.ini` que está sendo utilizado pelo Servidor Apache Web:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.2/apache2
```

O `phpinfo()` apenas retorna informações sobre PDO na seção "Module Authors":

```
MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia Alshanetsky, Johannes Schlueter
```

Mais informações:

- Sem nenhum arquivo `.htaccess`.
- Sem nenhum arquivo `.user.ini`.
- O Apache2 já foi reiniciado.
- Estou usando o mesmo código que funcionava bem com o PHP versão 7.2.13.

Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

É possivel que você tenha instalado o PHP7.3 sem instalar o PDO, já que em muitas distros algumas extensões são baixadas somente via repositório, o que as torna opcionais, então mesmo que habilite no php.ini, talvez a extensão não esteja disponivel, o que talvez irá só emitir erro no `display_startup_errors`.

Para tirar a prova real (não testei) experimente o seguinte comando:

```
php -n "<localização do php.ini usado no apache>/php.ini" -d display_startup_errors=1 -r "new PDO('mysql:dbname=foo;host=bar', 'user', 'pass');"
```

Claro que a resposta vai emitir o erro no terminal:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found.

Mas a flag `display_startup_errors=1` deve emitir erro se a extensão `pdo_mysql`, um tipo de erro que é só emitido quando o Apache inicia ou quando executa o PHP pelo terminal.

Tirado a prova se o problema é a extensão ter sido instalada ou não de fato em tua máquina/estação então confirme que após instalar o php7.3 se você executou os seguintes comandos (precisa fazer em `su` ou `sudo`):

```
 apt-get install php7.3-mysql
```

Depois de instalar o mysql habilitar o módulo:

```
 phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

Depois reiniciar o Apache:

```
 service apache2 restart
```